# Upgrade classic loadbalancer to network loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing

I am having trouble upgrading our CLB to a NLB. I did a manual upgrade via the wizard through the console, but the connectivity wouldn't work. This upgrade is needed so we can use static IPs in the loadbalancer. I think it needs to be upgraded through kubernetes, but my attempts failed.

What I (think I) understand about this setup is that this loadbalancer was set up using Helm. What I also understand is that the ingress (controller) is responsible for redirecting http requests to https. and that this lb is working on layer 4.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.30.0
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: nginx-ingress-external
  name: nginx-ingress-external-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/nginx-ingress-external-controller
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.20.41.16
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30854
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 30621
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: controller
    release: nginx-ingress-external
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: xxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com
```

How would I be able to perform the upgrade by modifying this configuration file?

Comment: I would suggest to create a new `Service` with the same selector.

Comment: @Jonas Only the selector? Component etc can be ignored?

Comment: I think Jonas is right, it's a good approach for me too.
In addition I suggest you to upgrade your helm chart to newer version (currently it is `v3.22.0`) and upgrade Helm to `v3`.
Is it possible for you to do these steps ?

Comment: @matt_j It seemed like the good approach indeed. It works now. Upgrading the chart is not possible at this moment though as my Helm skills are minimal.

Answer (score 1):

As **@Jonas** pointed out in the comments section, creating a new `LoadBalancer` `Service` with the same selector as the existing one is probably the fastest and easiest method. As a result we will have two `LoadBalancer` `Services` using the same `ingress-controller`.

You can see in the following snippet that I have two `Services` (`ingress-nginx-1-controller` and `ingress-nginx-2-controller`) with exactly the same endpoint:

```
$ kubectl get pod -o wide ingress-nginx-1-controller-5856bddb98-hb865
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP         
ingress-nginx-1-controller-5856bddb98-hb865   1/1     Running   0          55m   10.36.2.8

$ kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-1-controller ingress-nginx-2-controller
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     
ingress-nginx-1-controller   LoadBalancer   10.40.15.230   <PUBLIC_IP>   
ingress-nginx-2-controller   LoadBalancer   10.40.11.221   <PUBLIC_IP>   

$ kubectl get endpoints ingress-nginx-1-controller ingress-nginx-2-controller
NAME                         ENDPOINTS                    AGE
ingress-nginx-1-controller   10.36.2.8:443,10.36.2.8:80   39m
ingress-nginx-2-controller   10.36.2.8:443,10.36.2.8:80   11m
```

Additionally to avoid downtime, we can first change the DNS records to point at the new `LoadBalancer` and after the propagation time we can safely delete the old `LoadBalancer` `Service`.